# Is there a word for liking something out of spite?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

Basically, im trying to think of a word that means liking somsthing out of spite because someone you dislike hates something.

Closest I could come up with was vindictive. But that's not quite good enough.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I could come would be *[ambivalent](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ambivalent/%20ambivalent)*.

> Ambivalent: having mixed feelings or contradictory ideas about something or someone

or particularly its psychological use:

> Psychology. of or relating to the coexistence within an individual of positive and negative feelings toward the same person, object, or action, simultaneously drawing him or her in opposite directions.

You hate football because you don't like sports. But Chad hates football too, so you somewhat like football in that it is a source of hate for Chad, who himself is quite the dickhead. You are ambivalent towards football, in this sense.

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer, No.

`Out of spite` is a very distinctive set of words.  The most that you could do probably is move the words around a little.

> Lenora likes the show Friends despite her sister hating the show.
>
> David doesn't like pasta, but he orders it anyway despite his friends fear of pasta.

But you end up saying literally the same thing

> Tom told his daughter not to date the anarchist, but she did so anyway out of spite.
>
> Tom told his daughter not to date the anarchist, but she did so anyway despite him.

or, `despite his wishes`

Answer (score 0):

***Contrarian***

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contrarian): a person who takes an opposite or different position or attitude from other people

[Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/contrarian): opposing or rejecting popular opinion; going against current practice: *the comment came more from a contrarian disposition than moral conviction*

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/contrarian): a person who takes an opposing view, especially one who rejects the majority opinion, as in economic matters

[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/contrarian): a contrary or obstinate person